# JHipster - dynamic filtering for the entities using API call from elasticsearch - how to implement it with angular5 in a propper way?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, angular5, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and also I'm not so a experienced developer. So I have generated a Jhipster project and need a simple table with dynamic `column-filtering` option. I've already seen there is everything I need generated from Jhipster on `backend-side`.

So I have the generated Class **CustomerQueryService.java**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Customer> findByCriteria(CustomerCriteria criteria) {
    log.debug("find by criteria : {}", criteria);
    final Specifications<Customer> specification = createSpecification(criteria);
    return customerRepository.findAll(specification);
}

/**
 * Return a {@link Page} of {@link Customer} which matches the criteria from the database
 * @param criteria The object which holds all the filters, which the entities should match.
 * @param page The page, which should be returned.
 * @return the matching entities.
 */
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<Customer> findByCriteria(CustomerCriteria criteria, Pageable page) {
    log.debug("find by criteria : {}, page: {}", criteria, page);
    final Specifications<Customer> specification = createSpecification(criteria);
    return customerRepository.findAll(specification, page);
}

/**
 * Function to convert CustomerCriteria to a {@link Specifications}
 */
private Specifications<Customer> createSpecification(CustomerCriteria criteria) {
    Specifications<Customer> specification = Specifications.where(null);
    if (criteria != null) {
        if (criteria.getId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getId(), Customer_.id));
        }
        if (criteria.getLastName() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getLastName(), Customer_.lastName));
        }
        if (criteria.getName() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getName(), Customer_.name));
        }
        if (criteria.getPhoneNumber() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getPhoneNumber(), Customer_.phoneNumber));
        }
        if (criteria.getProvider() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getProvider(), Customer_.provider));
        }
        if (criteria.getVoNumber() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getVoNumber(), Customer_.voNumber));
        }
        if (criteria.getTransactionType() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getTransactionType(), Customer_.transactionType));
        }
        if (criteria.getKomponent() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getKomponent(), Customer_.komponent));
        }
        if (criteria.getActivationDate() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getActivationDate(), Customer_.activationDate));
        }
        if (criteria.getSimNumber() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getSimNumber(), Customer_.simNumber));
        }
        if (criteria.getOrderNumber() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getOrderNumber(), Customer_.orderNumber));
        }
        if (criteria.getTariff() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getTariff(), Customer_.tariff));
        }
        if (criteria.getOption() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getOption(), Customer_.option));
        }
        if (criteria.getHardware() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getHardware(), Customer_.hardware));
        }
        if (criteria.getImei() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getImei(), Customer_.imei));
        }
        if (criteria.getPurchasingPrice() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getPurchasingPrice(), Customer_.purchasingPrice));
        }
        if (criteria.getRetailPrice() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getRetailPrice(), Customer_.retailPrice));
        }
        if (criteria.getProvision() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getProvision(), Customer_.provision));
        }
        if (criteria.getMarge() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getMarge(), Customer_.marge));
        }
        if (criteria.getHwWkz() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getHwWkz(), Customer_.hwWkz));
        }
        if (criteria.getPaid() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getPaid(), Customer_.paid));
        }
        if (criteria.getEmployee() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getEmployee(), Customer_.employee));
        }
        if (criteria.getComment() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildStringSpecification(criteria.getComment(), Customer_.comment));
        }
    }
    return specification;
}
```

and another generated Class **CustomerCriteria.java**

```
public class CustomerCriteria implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private LongFilter id;

private StringFilter lastName;

private StringFilter name;

private LongFilter phoneNumber;

private StringFilter provider;

private LongFilter voNumber;

private StringFilter transactionType;

private StringFilter komponent;

private LocalDateFilter activationDate;

private LongFilter simNumber;

private LongFilter orderNumber;

private StringFilter tariff;

private StringFilter option;

private StringFilter hardware;

private LongFilter imei;

private BigDecimalFilter purchasingPrice;

private BigDecimalFilter retailPrice;

private BigDecimalFilter provision;

private BigDecimalFilter marge;

private BigDecimalFilter hwWkz;

private BooleanFilter paid;

private StringFilter employee;

private StringFilter comment;

public CustomerCriteria() {
}

public LongFilter getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(LongFilter id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public StringFilter getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(StringFilter lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public StringFilter getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(StringFilter name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public LongFilter getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(LongFilter phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public StringFilter getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(StringFilter provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

public LongFilter getVoNumber() {
    return voNumber;
}

public void setVoNumber(LongFilter voNumber) {
    this.voNumber = voNumber;
}

public StringFilter getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
}

public void setTransactionType(StringFilter transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
}

public StringFilter getKomponent() {
    return komponent;
}

public void setKomponent(StringFilter komponent) {
    this.komponent = komponent;
}

public LocalDateFilter getActivationDate() {
    return activationDate;
}

public void setActivationDate(LocalDateFilter activationDate) {
    this.activationDate = activationDate;
}

public LongFilter getSimNumber() {
    return simNumber;
}

public void setSimNumber(LongFilter simNumber) {
    this.simNumber = simNumber;
}

public LongFilter getOrderNumber() {
    return orderNumber;
}

public void setOrderNumber(LongFilter orderNumber) {
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
}

public StringFilter getTariff() {
    return tariff;
}

public void setTariff(StringFilter tariff) {
    this.tariff = tariff;
}

public StringFilter getOption() {
    return option;
}

public void setOption(StringFilter option) {
    this.option = option;
}

public StringFilter getHardware() {
    return hardware;
}

public void setHardware(StringFilter hardware) {
    this.hardware = hardware;
}

public LongFilter getImei() {
    return imei;
}

public void setImei(LongFilter imei) {
    this.imei = imei;
}

public BigDecimalFilter getPurchasingPrice() {
    return purchasingPrice;
}

public void setPurchasingPrice(BigDecimalFilter purchasingPrice) {
    this.purchasingPrice = purchasingPrice;
}

public BigDecimalFilter getRetailPrice() {
    return retailPrice;
}

public void setRetailPrice(BigDecimalFilter retailPrice) {
    this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
}

public BigDecimalFilter getProvision() {
    return provision;
}

public void setProvision(BigDecimalFilter provision) {
    this.provision = provision;
}

public BigDecimalFilter getMarge() {
    return marge;
}

public void setMarge(BigDecimalFilter marge) {
    this.marge = marge;
}

public BigDecimalFilter getHwWkz() {
    return hwWkz;
}

public void setHwWkz(BigDecimalFilter hwWkz) {
    this.hwWkz = hwWkz;
}

public BooleanFilter getPaid() {
    return paid;
}

public void setPaid(BooleanFilter paid) {
    this.paid = paid;
}

public StringFilter getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(StringFilter employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public StringFilter getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(StringFilter comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CustomerCriteria{" +
            (id != null ? "id=" + id + ", " : "") +
            (lastName != null ? "lastName=" + lastName + ", " : "") +
            (name != null ? "name=" + name + ", " : "") +
            (phoneNumber != null ? "phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", " : "") +
            (provider != null ? "provider=" + provider + ", " : "") +
            (voNumber != null ? "voNumber=" + voNumber + ", " : "") +
            (transactionType != null ? "transactionType=" + transactionType + ", " : "") +
            (komponent != null ? "komponent=" + komponent + ", " : "") +
            (activationDate != null ? "activationDate=" + activationDate + ", " : "") +
            (simNumber != null ? "simNumber=" + simNumber + ", " : "") +
            (orderNumber != null ? "orderNumber=" + orderNumber + ", " : "") +
            (tariff != null ? "tariff=" + tariff + ", " : "") +
            (option != null ? "option=" + option + ", " : "") +
            (hardware != null ? "hardware=" + hardware + ", " : "") +
            (imei != null ? "imei=" + imei + ", " : "") +
            (purchasingPrice != null ? "purchasingPrice=" + purchasingPrice + ", " : "") +
            (retailPrice != null ? "retailPrice=" + retailPrice + ", " : "") +
            (provision != null ? "provision=" + provision + ", " : "") +
            (marge != null ? "marge=" + marge + ", " : "") +
            (hwWkz != null ? "hwWkz=" + hwWkz + ", " : "") +
            (paid != null ? "paid=" + paid + ", " : "") +
            (employee != null ? "employee=" + employee + ", " : "") +
            (comment != null ? "comment=" + comment + ", " : "") +
        "}";
}
```

and in my **cusotmer.component.ts**

```
 searchByField(fieldName, fieldValue) {
    if (!fieldValue) {
        return this.clear();
    }
    this.page = 0;
    this.fieldName = fieldName,
    this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    this.router.navigate(['/customer', {
        fieldName: this.fieldName,
        fieldValue: this.fieldValue,
        page: this.page,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    }]);
    this.loadByField();
}
```

and in **customer.service.ts**

```
    searchByField(req?: any): Observable<HttpResponse<Customer[]>> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.resourceSearchFieldUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
        .map((res: HttpResponse<Customer[]>) => this.convertArrayResponse(res));
}
```

What I now want is to combine Searchqueries from each column in table and send it to elasticsearch api and get the right url for populating the search as shown below:

[image]

But unfortunately I can't combine the Search-parameters and didn't know how to modify that. I will also go the path from best practices and will also use the Classes which was already generated by `Jhipster` as I think it's the best way. Anyone have an idea how can I modify it ? Thank you very much for reading this long question in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
searchByField(fieldName, fieldValue) {
    if (!fieldValue) {
        return this.clear();
    }
    this.page = 0;
    this.router.navigate(['/customer', {
        this.fieldName:this.fieldValue; //   'customerName.contains': 'Jackson',
        page: this.page,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    }]);
    this.loadByField();
}
```